# Can I travel to UK if my UK Standard Visitor visa expires within a month?

Tags: indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas, visa-expiration

I have an Indian passport and have a Standard Visitor visa stamped twice but somehow I was not able to travel. Now I have plans to travel to UK but my visa is expiring within a month.

Can I travel?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but instead of the usual "up to six months at a time" for the duration of a visit if you do visit you must leave again within a month. That is, you can't stay in UK when you visa has expired.

Comment: Thanks,, This for sure that i ll leave from UK before visa gets expired. But only confusion was if there are any restrictions if Visa is about to expire within one month. I was thinking that there would be some conditions due to which i wont be able to travel.

Comment: @user54929 if the immigration officer thinks that you'll stay after your visa expires, you will have trouble getting into the UK.  In the normal case where you arrive with a credible description of your planned visit to the UK, including leaving on time, you won't have trouble.  The best way to have a credible description of your trip is to describe it truthfully.